# Extending NLog to write to a network drive doesn't do anything

Tags: f#, nlog

I'm trying to store my logs to a drive in the network. I wrote an nlog extension module:

```
module NLogExtension

open System.Text
open NLog
open NLog.LayoutRenderers
open NLog.Config
open System.IO

[<LayoutRenderer("FindAvailableDrive")>]
type FindAvailableDriveLayoutRenderer() = 
    inherit LayoutRenderer()
    let mutable validDrive = ""


    [<DefaultParameter>]
    member val DriveCandidates = "" with get, set
    member private x.findValidDrive(): string = 
        if x.DriveCandidates = null || x.DriveCandidates = ""
        then 
            if Directory.Exists("V:")
            then validDrive <- "V:"
            else validDrive <- "S:"
        else validDrive <- "S:"
        validDrive
    override x.Append(builder: StringBuilder, logEvent: LogEventInfo) = builder.Append(x.findValidDrive(): string) |> ignore
```

This is going to either store in V: or S: if V doesn't exist.

This is the nlog section in the App.config file:

```xml
<nlog 
    xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <extensions>
      <add assembly="Solk.NLogExtension" />
    </extensions>
    <targets>
      <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="logfile.txt" />
      <target name="indexCheckLog" 
              xsi:type="File"
              fileName="${FindAvailableDrive}/logs/indexChecklog.txt"
              layout="${callsite} - ${message}"
              archiveFileName="${FindAvailableDrive}/logs/archives/log.info.${shortdate}.txt"
              archiveEvery="Day"
              archiveNumbering = "Rolling"
              maxArchiveFiles="7"
              concurrentWrites="false"
      />
      <target name="console" xsi:type="Console" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="indexCheckLogger" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="indexCheckLog" final="true"/>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile" />
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="console" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
```

The target I'm concerned with is indexCheckLog. As you can see both the current log and the archive are using the extension `${FindAvailableDrive}`. You can see I added the extensions tag on top of the file with assembly `Solk.NLogExtension` (Solk is the assembly title and project name and NLogExtension is the name of the module as can be seen in the first line of the extension module).

However, not a single log is in these folders. Not in V or S. Not sure what I'm doing wrong and no exceptions are being thrown or any indications of what is exactly going on.

Comment: could you first test `${FindAvailableDrive}` by writing them to e.g. a file in temp folder? Also set `<nlog throwExceptions="true">` for the test (not in production!)

Comment: Sure, I will give that a try